# can't plot groupby object in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have applied the groupby method to my dataframe df in order to get an average at each value of my column X (percentage)

```
df1 = df.groupby('percentage')['ratio'].mean()
```

that is for each percentage value, I have an average of the ratio value(because I had many data points).

now I want to plot new percentage (X) vs new ratio values (Y) but I can't somehow.
df1[:,0] gives me an error message as if it isn't the write call for my first column.

how could I plot those 2 columns?

this is the output of df1:

```
percentage
0.000000    0.987699
0.000144    0.974359
0.000461    0.930000
0.001427    0.880549
0.006119    0.968185
0.008497    0.968686
0.017821    0.970008
0.028747    0.976759
0.030128    0.975607
0.038823    0.979795
0.043440    0.979847
Name: ratio, Length: 61, dtype: float64
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I am simply trying now to access the first column. I don't understand why df1.iloc[:,0] doesn't give the first column as output. could you help by any chance?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: indexing error:
IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-ffc3c89c6403> in <module>
----> 1 df1.iloc[:,0]
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1470             except (KeyError, IndexError):
   1471                 pass
-> 1472             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1473         else:
   1474             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

Comment: try: `df1.reset_index().plot()`

Comment: Thanks @rotem tal provided the right answer

Comment: @PandasKoala  pls take a look of other solutions as they also use `.plot()` method of the df. If you wanna use matplotlib, pls be clear about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's really weird, but `df1` is a series, not dataframe. the line on the left is the series index, while on the right is the values, so `print(df[0.017821])` would print `0.970008`, you can still access these values

```
percentage = list(df1.index)
ratio = df1.values
```

This is why you received the error message, series have a single axis

Answer (score 2):

`df1` is a `pandas.Series`. With pandas it is possible to use maplotlib with builtin functions like [`pandas.plot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html). You could do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
axes = df1.plot()
axes.set_ylabel(df1.name)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just plot `df1`.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

p = [.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7, .8,.9]
p = [random.choice(p) for _ in range(180)]
r = np.linspace(.001, .999, num=180)

df = pd.DataFrame({'pct':p, 'ratio':r})
df1 = df.groupby('pct')['ratio'].mean()
df1.plot()
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Comment: typo: `np.random`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access specific columns because you're dealing with series instead of a dataframe.

```
type(df.groupby('percentage')['ratio'].mean())
# pandas.core.series.Series
```

I think `.reset_index()` should help, as it converts your results into dataframe

```
type(df.groupby('percentage')['ratio'].mean().reset_index())
# pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

So, once you use `.reset_index()`, you could assign columns to variables:

```
new_df = df.groupby('percentage')['ratio'].mean().reset_index()
x, y = (new_df['percentage'], new_df['ratio'])
```